# Python: How would I sort a specific list within a nested dict?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this sort of structure:

```
{"model":{.."blah":[{...}],"loop_2110C":[{"EQ":{"EQ01":["30","47","AG","42","AD","AF","BF","BG","14","45","10"]}, "blah":"....
```

And so on.  Its a dict of nested dicts with some of the keys having lists as values.  All of the sort routines I've tried so far sort all of the keys with the dicts.  I only want specific lists (the values within, such as the EQ01 above) to be sorted.  I can't allow any of the other keys to be sorted out of order.

Is sorting just that particular EQ01 list possible without affecting the rest of the dicts?

Comment: `dictionary[...][...]...[...].sort()` should work provided you know the keys that would point to the list you want to sort

Comment: Thanks @rdas.  The only issue is that while I might know the key to go after, I may not know at what level it is nested at.  It will vary greatly as this is not a static structure.  This is basically a JSON model built off a medical transaction.  I'd show the whole structure, but due to PHI I cannot.

Comment: First write a function to find the item that you want to sort. This would be a recursive search through the dict. Then once you have the item references, you can sort each of them in-place using `.sort`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   dic[model][loop_2110C][0][EQ][EQ01].sort()
```

list.sort()

it sort in ascending order by default

if you want to reverse it then use

```
   reverse= True
```

inside the parameters of sort function